# Sum of 2^x using elements of a list as exponents

Tags: python, list, exponent

Given a list containing integers :

```
>>> print mylist
[0, 1, 2]
```

Can I calculate the sum of `2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2` ? the base number (2) is fixed, it does not change, I'm just using the elements of list as exponents

#### related doubts :

Is a list suitable for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you do some testing and find out?

Comment: because I was in doubt that a list was a suitable data structure to achieve that

Comment: And your doubts would have been resolved one way or the other if you had tested it. That's exactly what testing is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it is.

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2]
print sum([2**x for x in mylist])
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: Use this one, not the other answers with `^` instead of `**`.  `^` performs a bit-wise exclusive or (xor).  For instance, 2 ^ 2 == 0 (binary 10 xor 10 == 00) and 2 ^ 1 == 3 (binary 10 xor 01 == 11).

Comment: @Colin good point, didn't realize about that. Funny thing is that I wrote output 5 and all the others wrote 5 too... damn those copy&paste xDDD

Comment: You can also use `sum(2**x for x in my list)`; you don't to build a list object just to pass to `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [0,1,2]
mysum = 0
for i in mylist:
    mysum = mysum + 2**i


>>> print mysum
7
```

Comment: Please, do not hide built-in function `sum` with a variable `sum`

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use `map()` and `lambda` expression as :

```
print sum(map(lambda x:2**x, mylist))
>>> 7
```

Comment: Passing a user-defined function to `map` is generally less efficient than simply using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you *could* use a `list`, but, given the linear nature of its elements, it'd probably be better to just use a `range()` object:

```
mynum = 2
mysum = sum(2**x for x in range(mynum+1))
```

Comment: You're assuming the list is contiguous; what about `mylist = [ 0, 3, 5, 7]`?

Comment: The list in the example _is_ contiguous (linear, anyway - `range(0, 10, 3)` is discontiguous but linear). That's why I suggested `range()`. I figured there was a good chance that the OP's use cases involved such a pattern. If more information was provided that revealed the use of non-linear `list`s, that would be different.

Answer (score 0):

an alternate way of doing this without using list is :

`x=0
for i in range(0,3):
        x= x + pow(2,i)
print "%d" % x`

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
mylist = [0,1,2]
sum(2**i for i in mylist)
```